# Is there a way to to assign specific Heroku dyno to handle requests to specific URL?

Tags: http, heroku, concurrency

In my app I have a URL on which I receive POST HTTP requests from 3rd party server. I would like to have only 1 dyno to handle it to simplify synchronization.

Is there a way to assign in Heroku a single dyno to specific URL?

My setup: Heroku (bamboo stack), 10 dynos, Ruby on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1):

A single dyno will be randomly selected from among your web dynos when you POST to your app. You can't choose which of your running dynos will be selected.  Why would you want to choose a specific dyno?  It feels like you may have difficulty scaling and handling failure if you do that?

Comment: I aggregate the posts events in queue (ruby's construct), and I prefer to have a single queue in a single dyno, instead of having multiple queues, or saving events in a storage.

Comment: I see.  I recommend using an external queue - a queue with a backing service. That way you can have multiple worker dynos listening to it as wel. I suspect this will scale better in the end too.  I recently put together a small example of such an app, perhaps it will help: https://github.com/jonmountjoy/queue_classic_demo

Comment: Thaks @Jon Mounjoy, seems interesting, will take a look

Comment: why? because a dyno for only admin functions and a dyno for IOT functions makes a LOT of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't architect your app in a way that requires a certain type of requests always hitting the same dyno. Instead of building state in ephemeral storage (i.e. filesystem or memory of one dyn0), store it someplace safe that's accessible to all dynos running your app.

Comment: I don't want "always the same" dyno, I just want "always only one dyno", chosen randomly for all I care.